# How to get a DHT22/AM2302 sensor to work with MCP23017 I2C Port Expander

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I am building out a monitoring and automation system for my various greenhouses in the garden. Due to the number of devices that need to be controlled and monitored rather than purchasing additional Raspberry PIs I decided to go with a GPIO port expander and make use of the existing Raspberry PI hardware.

I have however managed to hit a "wall" when it comes to reading the DHT22 Temperature and Humidity sensor when I connect it up via the MCP23017. I know I have the MCP23017 connected correctly as I am able make LEDs flash and relay switches turn on and off.

None of these require reading data from the device connected though and this where I am running into the problem and would really appreciate any help or advice.

I am running a Revison 2 Raspberry PI A, sudo i2cdetect -y 1 shows MCP23017 connected to 0X20.

I am using Python 2.7 for the coding, using the Adafruit_DHT module and for addressing the MCP23017 I am using the wiringpi2 module. Although I am open to other suggestions here with regards to using wiringpi2.

The Adafruit_DHT uses the following syntax to connect to and retrieve information from the sensor:

```
import Adafruit_DHT    
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
pin = 7   
humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
```

The above works fine when connecting directly to one of the "standard" GPIO ports. However I have not worked out how to address the additional new GPIO ports in this same manner i.e.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
import Adafruit_DHT
import wiringpi2
wiringpi2.wiringPiSetupGpio()
wiringpi2.mcp23017Setup(65,0x20)

for n in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16):
  humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor22, wiringpi2.digitalRead(n+64))
  print n, humidity, temperature
```

So the above cycles through each new port, however I don't get any results back, as I say if I connect the device directly the GPIOs on the PI is works fine. I suspect the issue with how I am telling the driver which PIN to use.

I would really appreciate any advice or help on this issue. As I said I am open to other ideas on how to use this DHT22 with the MCP23017.

Comment: Did you try configuring the pin to which you connected the DHT as an input pin? `wiringpi2.pinMode(GP_number, 0)`. If you haven't, try. Also configure the pin to use a pull-up.

Comment: I will give that a go when I get home, seems really obvious now.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, I think the problem is with using wiringpi2.digitalRead(), rather than just passing the GPIO address directly to the Adafruit_DHT driver, if that makes sense.

Comment: You're *assuming* the problem is with `digitalRead`, but there's no evidence for that yet. Might I suggest to have a look at this [blog-entry](http://raspi.tv/2013/using-the-mcp23017-port-expander-with-wiringpi2-to-give-you-16-new-gpio-ports-part-3) of someone who managed to successfully do what you're trying to do?

Comment: Oliver W - Yup took a look at this blog entry early on in the process. It was this that lead me to believe I could do what I wanted i.e. DHT22 sensors connected to the MCP23017. Unfortunately these sensors DHT22 and DHT11 are both proving to be a challenge to get working with wiringpi2 for python. Moisture probes work fine, relay switches work fine, it is just these particular sensors that don't seem to like how I am addressing or trying to address them.

Comment: You might have to rewrite the library to specifically work with the MCP23017. Adafruit's c library (which python is using) is setting the pin as an output and pulsing the DHT sensor and then setting the pin as an input and recording pulse widths from the sensor.  
[link](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/blob/master/source/Raspberry_Pi_2/pi_2_dht_read.c)